# Use Room + Paging3 + LazyColumn but pagination is not implemented

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-paging-3

I have the following code, but I don't think the pagination is implemented.

dao

```kotlin
interface IArticleDao {
    @Query(
        """
        SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY :order DESC
    """
    )
    fun pagingSource(order: String): PagingSource<Int, Article>
}
```

Repository

```kotlin
class ArticleRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val articleDao: IArticleDao
) {
    fun list(order: String) = articleDao.pagingSource(order)
}
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ArticleViewModel @Inject constructor(private val articleRepository: ArticleRepository) : ViewModel() {
    fun list(order: String) = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20)){
        articleRepository.list(order)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

Screen

```kotlin
    val articleViewModel = hiltViewModel<ArticleViewModel>()
    val lazyArticleItem = articleViewModel.list("id").collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    ArticlePage(lazyArticleItem)
```

ArticlePage

```kotlin
    LazyColumn{
    items(...)
    when(val state = lazyArticleItem.loadState.append){
                is LoadState.Error -> {
                    println("error")
                }
                is LoadState.Loading -> {
                    println("${lazyArticleItem.itemCount}, ${lazyArticleItem.itemSnapshotList}")
                }
                else -> {}
            }
}
```

`lazyArticleItem.itemCount` printed the number 668, so I don't think the pagination is working properly, but the data displayed on the UI interface is fine, it's just not paginated by 20 items per page.

Comment: @Klitos G. Sorry to bother you, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74968933/i-dont-know-why-android-paging3-with-roomdatabase-and-compose-return-entire-dat) similar to mine and you answered it. But this problem has not been solved in the end, can you please take a look at my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `PagingConfig`, you can specify `enablePlaceholders`, which is true by default (your case). If placeholders are enabled and paging source knows the total number of items, which it knows when it takes data from room database, `lazyArticleItem.itemSnapshotList` size will be the total size of the source, only the elements that are not yet loaded will be `null`.

So you can't say that paging is not working based on `itemCount`. You are also printing `itemSnapshotList`, are there `null`s? You can also try setting `enablePlaceholders = false`, `itemCount` then corresponds to the number of loaded items.

Comment: Yes, set enablePlaceholders is true can solve this problem. But if the default setting of Room is `enablePlaceholders=false`, then this is recommended. If there are tens of thousands of records in my table, won't querying the database once affect performance and memory?

Comment: No, it doesn't query the database for all the items. It only queries it for total count, which is cheap, and then it loads pages of items. So it knows the total count, but never actually access the items until you need them.

Comment: I have another question I want to ask, can you see why the data I queried is not in reverse order according to id? The sql statement is `SELECT * FROM t_article ORDER BY id DESC`, The result set obtained by directly using the run sql query is in reverse order according to the id.

Comment: That's weird, I have no idea why this might be happening. If you are sure that two functions with the same sql statement, one returning `List` and the other `PagingSource`, produce result with different ordering, you should probably file a bug report to the room/paging library.

Comment: Just tested, if the return type is `List`, then it is the correct result, and the order is reversed according to the id. `dao` returns `PageSource` instead of a custom `PageSource`, is it possible that this is the reason?

Comment: what does "dao returns PageSource instead of a custom PageSource" mean?

Comment: I saw that the document has customized an ExamplePageSource inherited from PageSource `class ExamplePagingSource( ... ) : PagingSource<Int, User>()`. I see `PagingSource` that is directly returned in the Room documentation, not `ExamplePagingSource`

Comment: No, I don"t think so, it looks like a bug

Comment: I found the problem, Room does not support passing `columnName`